# Difference between Windows Phone project and Silverlight Windows Phone project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I recently updated my Visual Studio 2013 such now it allows to develop Windows Phone 8.1 applications.
But now, when I create a Windows Phone project, it is systematically for WP 8.1 and I can't change the target.
The only way I found in order to develop WP 8.0 apps it's to create Silverlight Windows Phone project.

Whence my question : What's the concrete difference between Windows Phone project and Silverlight Windows Phone projet in Visual Studio 2013 ?

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Windows Phone project uses the Windows Runtime APIs. A lot of the Windows Runtime API introduced in Windows Phone 8 project is common to both Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8, making it easier to write once and share code between your apps on both platforms.

As expected the Windows Phone Silverlight project uses the Silverlight based APIs.